# Angular: how to format date input value which is not being interpolated?

Tags: angular, date, angular-pipe

I'm assigning values to date inputs in the .ts class like this:

```
this.forma.controls.releaseDate.setValue(
  this.DatafromApi.propOne["0"].releaseDate
);
```

the values obtaining from the API comes in this format: `"2019092300000000"`

I'm trying to apply Angular date pipes to format it like this: `dd/mm/yyyy`, but since I'm not doing string interpolation I don't know how to apply | date.  If I were assigning the value in the template I'd just use the date pipe, but since I'm assigning the value in the .ts component file I just don't know how to accomplish it.

this is the .ts file:

```
import { AuthService } from "./../../../../core/consultaService/auth.service";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ReportesService } from "../../../../core/consultaService/reportes.service";
import { UtilService } from "../../../../services/util.service";

import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
  FormControl
} from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: "app-detalle-nc-descuento-omitido",
  templateUrl: "./detalle-nc-descuento-omitido.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./detalle-nc-descuento-omitido.component.scss"]
})
export class DetalleNcDescuentoOmitidoComponent implements OnInit {
  forma: FormGroup;
  fechaActual = new Date();
  user: any;
  selectedNote: any;
  descripcionArticulos: any;

  articulosArray = [];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public cargador: NgxSpinnerService,
    private reportesService: ReportesService,
    private utilService: UtilService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
    this.forma = new FormGroup({
      releaseDate: new FormControl(),
      secondDate: new FormControl(),

    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.forma.controls.releaseDate.setValue(
      this.selectedNote.dataUno["0"].releaseDate
    );
    this.forma.controls.secondDate.setValue(
      this.selectedNote.dataUno["0"].releaseDate
    );
  }
}
```

this is the html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Second Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 pl-0">
      <input formControlName="secondDate" name="secondDate" class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Release Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3 pl-0">
      <input formControlName="releaseDate" name="releaseDate" class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it a date picker or just a text field?

Comment: can you please share your component.html as well as component.ts

Comment: it's just a text field to show data to the user.

Comment: Bear, as requested I shared the .ts and .html files :)

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If so would u update with what your TS and HTML looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular built in  date pipe in your component.ts file as follows, first you should add your date pipe in your modules providers array. So that you can inject the DatePipe in your component.ts later.

`providers: [DatePipe]`

In your component.ts do the following.

`import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'`

Inject the date pipe in your component constructor

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
```

In your `ngOnInit` before setting the value of input fields, transform the data using `DatePipe.transform` method

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const releaseDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.selectedNote.dataUno["0"].releaseDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy');

    const secondDate= this.datePipe.transform(this.selectedNote.dataUno["0"].releaseDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy');

    this.forma.controls.releaseDate.setValue(releaseDate);
    this.forma.controls.secondDate.setValue(secondDate);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DatePipe filter

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';


 constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
   this.datePipe.transform(your_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
 }
```

Also, make sure to add it to the provider list

```
providers: [DatePipe ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous comment, use DatePipe. An example, an excerpt from my current project:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="control">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Control Date </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.control | date:'d MMMM yyyy' }} </td>
</ng-container>
```

where `{{element.control }}` contains date (1999-12-01) and with `| date:'d MMM yyyy'` transform to 01 December 1999.

I hope to help you

Comment: The thing is that I'm not interpolating the value in the html like you are doing, my friend. I posted my html and ts files. Please have a look at them.